# Javascript Regex multiple group matches in pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, grouping

I have a question for a Javascript regex ninja: How could I simplify my variable creation from a string using regex grouping? I currently have it working without using any grouping, but I would love to see a better way!

The string is:

```
var url = 'resources/css/main.css?detect=#information{width:300px;}';
```

The code that works is:

```
var styleStr = /[^=]+$/.exec(url).toString();
var id = /[^\#][^\{]+/.exec(styleStr).toString();
var property = /[^\{]+/.exec(/[^\#\w][^\:]+/.exec(styleStr)).toString();
var value = /[^\:]+/.exec(/[^\#\w\{][^\:]+[^\;\}]/.exec(styleStr)).toString();
```

This gives:

```
alert(id)       //information
alert(property) //width
alert(value)    //300px
```

Any takers?

Comment: In fact, the grammar of CSS selectors is a little more complex. (See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/grammar.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure..

```
var url = 'resources/css/main.css?detect=#information{width:300px;}';
var matches = url.match(/#([^{]+){([^:]+):([^;]+)/);
var id = matches[1];
var property = matches[2];
var value = matches[3];
```

Comment: I think the RegEx for multiple match should be like /RegEx/g, otherwise it will return only first match. So in above answer, it should have been `var matches = url.match(/#([^{]+){([^:]+):([^;]+)/g);`

Answer (score 1):

```
#(?<type>.+){(?<property>.*?):(?<value>.*?);

Group "type":   information     31      11
Group "property":   width       43       5
Group "value":  300px
```

[Jay loves regexbuddy]

JS:

```
result = subject.match(/#([\s\S]+)\{([\s\S]*?):([\s\S]*?);/ig);
```